# How to use "seem"

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sentences is correct?

- *It seems that you have a nice car.*
- *You seem to have a nice car.*

Comment: Assuming that it is true that he has a nice car, and assuming that the speaker is aware of that, then both sentences are true. They are also both grammatical, and they mean the same thing. They are the product of two very different syntactic rules, one Extraposing **That you have a new car seems (to me)* and leaving a dummy _it_ subject behind, and the other Subject-Raising _You_ to be the subject of _seem_ from  **(For) you to have a nice car seems (to me)*.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Isn't the possession of a nice car tentatively inferred *from some aspect or circumstance of the supposed possessor himself* in the second example, while in the first it may have been inferred from mere gossip to that effect?

Comment: That's not a meaning difference; that's a different invited inference. And it's tentative. Syntactic differences among constructions with the same verbs often serve to provide platforms for different inferences and implicatures.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, it is clearer that "seem" doesn't really predicate anything of its superficial subject for "idiom part" cases, like "Careful track seems to have been kept of his movements", or "The shit really seems to have hit the fan."

Comment: @John Lawler, Amirbaderestani asked "how to use seem".  This seems like more than a request for help with the grammatical or syntactical usage, don't you think?  Although, the question, "Which of the following sentences is correct" would seem to bolster your view. Perhaps Amirbaderestani can state more clearly the sort of advice he is looking for, and for what purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know which sentence is correct.  I suspect you may also want to know under what conditions a person might use either sentence.

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

Their meaning may *seem* straightforward but one wonders why the speaker does not simply state, "You have a nice car".

Several possibilities come to mind, each of which touches on the pragmatics of the utterances.  Of course we would need to know more about the circumstances in which either of the phrases was uttered.  Here are some circumstances that might help to convey why the qualification, "it seems", or the alternative, "you seem", was used.

Imagine that...

-you asked a friend, well-versed in automobile mechanics and repair, to inspect a car you are thinking about purchasing.   After he carefully inspects the car, he may express a cautious approval by saying, "It seems you have a nice car." In such a case, "it seems" may convey the sense of "To the best of my knowledge, the car appears to be in proper working order."

-you and some friends are talking about a car you recently purchased. (The car is not present.)  They are complimenting you on your purchase and mentioning some of the things they like about it.  One of your friends that is present has not seen the car but has just heard the praise that others have lavished on it. The phrase, "It seems you have a nice car," acknowledges the praise of others.

-a somewhat cynical friend who has learned that your car broke down several times over the past week sarcastically states: "it seems you have a nice car."

-a friend of yours shows up in a new car.  You say, "you seem to have a nice car" to convey your first impression.

I see very little difference, in these cases, in whether one uses the first or the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct. In the first one "it" is an "empty subject" and in the second one there is no empty subject. Perhaps using an empty subject conveys a more impersonal meaning, but despite the difference in connotation I see no difference in the general meaning.

Comment: I can't shake the suspicion that in *some* contexts those "more impersonal" connotations might imply *seems **to other people / the world at large***, rather than just *seems **to me***. In some contexts, such as *We wanted to go to [The Fat Duck](http://www.thefatduck.co.uk/), but it seems they don't serve 24/7 nudists* the "semblance" (to *everybody*) is so strongly implied it really means *turned out, transpired*, rather than simply *appeared, gave the impression that*. And I don't think *they seem not to serve...* would be quite so likely with that nuance.